# Loading DLL in external program?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, class-library

I have a C# ClassLibrary that contains a function to sum two numbers:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int Calc(int i, int b) {
            return i + b;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load this dll from other C# application externally. How can I do this?

Comment: if you use visual studio: add reference, and then search your dll

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It might not be as obvious (what is obvious anyway) as it seems; see @minitech's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean you want to load it dynamically, by file name? Then yes, you can use the [`Assembly.LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) method as follows:

```
// Load the assembly
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Path\To\Your\DLL.dll");

// Load the type and create an instance
Type t = a.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Calculator");
object instance = a.CreateInstance("ClassLibrary1.Calculator");

// Call the method
MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Calc");
m.Invoke(instance, new object[] {}); // Get the result here
```

(Translated example from [here](http://truevbdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-reflection-to-dynamically-load.html), but I wrote it so don't worry!)

Answer (score 2):

Just building on the answer by minitech.. If you can use C# 4.0 you can omit some reflection calls.

```
    public static void Main()
    {  
       Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(@"PathToLibrar\ClassLibraryTest.dll");
       var type = ass.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Calculator");
       dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
       int add = instance.Calc(1, 3);
    }
```

Here as `instance` of of type `dynamic`, you don't have to find the method `Calc` by reflection.

But the best way is to define a interface upstream

```
 public interface ICalculator
    {
        int Calc(int i, int b);
    }
```

and implement it in your class downstream

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Calc(int i, int b)
    {
        return i + b;
    }
}
```

Then you can do reflection minimally to construct the object.

```
    public static void Main()
    {  
       Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(@"PathToLibrar\ClassLibraryTest.dll");
       var type = ass.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Calculator");
       ICalculator instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ICalculator;
       int add = instance.Calc(1, 3);
    }
```

This will give you the best performance.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the References in the project explorer in Visual Studio and simply select the assembly. Then you can use it:

```
using ClassLibrary1;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        int result = calc.Cal(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case your'e using visual studio you can reference this dll in your project and than include  the namespace in your new source code